# How do I test a feature that has multiple outcomes using cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumberjs

I am using Selenium and cucumber to perform behaviour driven tests.
I have the following feature:

```
Scenario: User changes name
  When User changes name
  Then User can see "Name has been updated"
  And User can see the updated name
```

however, on this website, sometimes there is an error with the server so the name might not update, in which case it will say 'name has not been updated' and the updated name won't be shown. This is an acceptable response, but how would I test this scenario using cucumber, covering both situations?

Like something like an if then else statement but in cucumber.

Comment: I formatted your scenario to make it more readable, put it in a block surrounded by ```

Answer (score 0):

You should setup the site so it gives a consistent result, using a Given.

```
Given site is accepting name changes
When User changes name
Then User can see "Name has been updated"
And User can see the updated name
```

```
Given site is not accepting name changes
When User changes name
Then User can see "Name has not been updated"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get consistent results from the website I would play around with your step definition.
For example would do something like:

```
Scenario: User changes name
  When User changes name
  Then User can see the updated name
```

And in your step definition I would go for something like:

pseudocode:

```java
Boolean pass = false;
String elementText = driver.findElement(...).getText();
if(elementText.equals("actual name") || elementText.equals("Name has not been updated") {
   pass = true;
}
assertTrue(pass);
```

Or something like that. But still I would rethink this test scenario as maybe there is a better approach to test this feature.